# tf.data.TFRecordDataset.shard affecting accuracy baseline Tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-datasets

I noticed that when I sharded my datasets, the accuracy_baseline stayed exactly the same throughout the training session. However, once I removed the sharding piece, the accuracy_baseline fluctuates.

Does anyone have any insights as to the reason why sharding causes the accuracy baseline to be the same? Below is the function that I use.

Thanks

```
def input_fn(filenames, train, batch_size=5, buffer_size=10):
    epoch = None
    if t rain != True:
        epoch = 1

    if run_config.task_type == "ps":
        worker_num   = None
        worker_index = None
    elif run_config.task_type == "master":
        worker_num   = run_config._num_worker_replicas
        worker_index = 0
    else:
        worker_num   = run_config._num_worker_replicas
        worker_index = run_config.task_id + 1

    d = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=filenames)
    d = d.shard(worker_num,worker_index)
    d = d.repeat(epoch)
    d = d.shuffle(buffer_size)
    d = d.map(parse)
    d = d.batch(batch_size)
    d = d.prefetch(1)

    iterator      = d.make_one_shot_iterator()
    X, label      = iterator.get_next()
```